# how can I stop music in one activity and start another music in next activity?

Tags: android, audio, android-activity

I have 3 activity, when I move from 1st act.to 2nd act. one music will start, and when I move from 2nd act. to 3rd act., 2nd activity's music should stop and 3rd activity's music should start. As per my coding, 2nd activity's music is stopping, but 3rd activity's music does not start. my code is given here-under: please help me.

```
//1st activity code start
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b;
    static MediaPlayer mp;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.bakaratwozeroone);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butmove);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mp.start();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
//1st activity code end

//2nd activity code start
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b;
    static MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mumfive);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butmove2);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mp.start();


                startActivity(new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main3Activity.class));
            }
        });
    }
        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            if(mp !=null);
            mp.release();
            mp = null;

    }
}
//2nd activity code end
```

Comment: I did not understand from you link

Answer (score 0):

No need to keep MediaPlayer instance on every activity, Use BoundService to run media player and make communication with Service and activities.

For reference,use this link

https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Music-Player